# didUpdateUserLocation not firing inside view with background updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I have an app that uses background location updates, it needs to constantly track the devices position regardless if the app is in the foreground or background. I have the background tracking setup in the app delegate.

In the front end I have a single UIViewController with a working mapkit view all the CCLocationManager code triggers without error but didUpdateUserLocation is never fired within the custom UIViewController class.

Background location tracking is working with absolutely no problems.

Here is the code i'm using in viewDidLoad

```
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setShowsPointsOfInterest:YES];

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[self.locationManager setDelegate:self];

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

NSString *error;
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {error = @"Error message";}

CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {error = @"Error message";}

if (error) {NSLog(error);}
else
{
    status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;

    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check below details:

1. Testing this on simulator?? didUpdateLocations must be tested on real device.
2. Make sure that you specified the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription string or else the app won't present the authorization message, and you won't be authorized.
3. Have you implemented locationManager:didFailWithError:? did you got any error?
4. Have you implemented locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:? Are you getting this called with a successful authorization status?

Comment: 1. Testing on the Simulator works just fine, the background location changes work from the simulator with no problems.

2. Yes otherwise the background update locations also wouldn't work.

3. No error
4. Authorization happens successfully without any errors

Comment: It can be very silly but did you forgot to define you ViewController to use <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> .... @interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>

Comment: Does the order matter?
UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>

Also i just checked and I'm getting kCLErrorDomain Code=0 i've set a default location in the schema however

Comment: Order should not matter. But based on the error you mentioned it looks like network is not available. Or otherwise you need to reset the network setting as well as location settings

Comment: Also If Scheme/Edit Scheme/Options/Allow Location Simulation is checked but default location is not set on simulator it shows the mentioned error.

Comment: But the same code works perfectly when called from the AppDelegate just not from this view. The entire situation is identical.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the problem finally.

Turns out even if you're using the location stuff in Schema and Xcode you still need to set it in the Simulator via Debug > Location

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

and now, with iOS 9, the following needs to be included for any update;

```
if ([ locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization  )])
    {
     locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;

    }
```

Else background updates will be impaired.